# How to read value from daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I have this daterangepicker runs on my local PHP site. Here is the code for HTML part

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline" method="post" action="">

    <div id="reportrange" class="form-control">
         <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
         <span></span> 
         <b class="caret"></b>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-white" type="submit">Search</button>

</form>
```

Javascript part:

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();

    $('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract(29, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        autoApply: true,
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
        endDate: moment(),
        minDate: '01/01/2012',
        maxDate: '12/31/2015',
        dateLimit: { days: 60 },
        showDropdowns: true,
        showWeekNumbers: true,
        timePicker: false,
        timePickerIncrement: 1,
        timePicker12Hour: true,
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        },
        opens: 'right',
        drops: 'down',
        buttonClasses: ['btn', 'btn-sm'],
        applyClass: 'btn-primary',
        cancelClass: 'btn-default',
        separator: ' to ',
        locale: {
            applyLabel: 'Submit',
            cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
            fromLabel: 'From',
            toLabel: 'To',
            customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
            daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr','Sa'],
            monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            firstDay: 1
        }
    }, function(start, end, label) {
            console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    });
```

I can select the date well, But no readable value on submit. Already follow this suggestion [getting the value of daterangepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651943/getting-the-value-of-daterangepicker-bootstrap/33431570#33431570) but still no luck. Any helps is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here [easy-to-use-bootstrap-date-range-picker](http://mycodestock.blogspot.co.id/2014/01/easy-to-use-bootstrap-date-range-picker.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `daterangepicker` library will dynamically create an `<input>` tag with `name="daterange"`. So, when you submit your form, the `daterange` form variable should contain the value you want. It will be formatted something like this:

> 01/15/2015 - 02/15/2015

If that is not a format that you want, you could create two hidden input fields (one for start date and one for end date) and set their values whenever your date range is changed.

```
<input type="hidden" name="start">
<input type="hidden" name="end">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate;
$('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').endDate;
```

This question solves it all.In my case the answer was not working because I was accessing the value before Declaring a date range picker.
[getting the value of daterangepicker bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651943/getting-the-value-of-daterangepicker-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

You may use default php function explode() and it will return array with 2 elements

```
        $daterange = $_POST['date_range'];
        $split = explode('-', $daterange);

        #check make sure have 2 elements in array
        $count = count($split);
        if($count <> 2){
          #invalid data
        }

        $start = $split[0];
        $end = $split[1];
```